# menu does't resize with window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

my menu looks now like that:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

wh ymenu doesnt resize with window? how can i fix it?

**edit:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgCzY.png

Comment: please show some code (xaml) to figure out your problem

Comment: Don't use a GUI designer and it'll happen automatically.

Comment: i think your horizontal alignements are wrong, look at these and use Stretch...

Comment: edited, i dont see right option in properties though : (

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple example

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Menu Grid.Row="0">
     <MenuItem Header="File"/>
     <MenuItem Header="Another"/>
  </Menu>
  <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I normally just use the Dock Property.  Check out [MSDN Control.Dock Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) documentation. Also, make sure your Menu bar belongs to the window and not another container.  It works for me.  I hope this helps.